# Download venues not work - Foursquare API php (search/venues)

Tags: php, json, api, foursquare

when i try to download the venues from foursquare with the venues search api (e.g. api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?near=newyork) it return an empty json.

Here the code (php):

```
<?php

      require_once("FoursquareAPI.class.php");

      // Set your client key and secret
      $client_key = "GHXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
      $client_secret = "REXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

      // Load the Foursquare API library
      $foursquare = new FoursquareAPI($client_key,$client_secret);

      // Prepare parameters
      $params = array("near"=>str_replace(' ', '', $_GET['place']));

      // Perform a request to a authenticated-only resource
      $response = $foursquare->GetPublic("venues/search",$params);
      $venues = json_decode($response);

      echo $venues;
?>
```

$venues is empty but i don't understand why.. any suggestion?

ps. `$_GET['place'] = "newyork"` and here work (developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=venues/search%3Fnear%3Dnewyork)

Thanks a lot, Andrea.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem and it turned out that I didn't have curl library installed. After installing curl library everything started working just fine. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! Even if 3 years and 8 months after